# Numba and Cython aren't improving the performance compared to CPython significantly, maybe I am using it incorrectly?

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numba

BIG EDIT:

================

For the sake of clarity, I am removing the old results and replace it by the more recent results. The question is still the same: Am I using both Cython and Numba correctly, and what improvements to the code can be made? (I have a newer and more bare-bones temporary IPython notebook with all the code and results [here](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/rasbt/One-Python-benchmark-per-day/blob/master/ipython_nbs/scratch/python_cython_numba.ipynb?create=1))

## 1)

I think I figured out why there was initially no difference between Cython, Numba, and CPython: It was because I fed them

numpy arrays as input:

```
x = np.asarray([x_i*np.random.randint(8,12)/10 for x_i in range(n)])
```

instead of lists:

```
x = [x_i*random.randint(8,12)/10 for x_i in range(n)]
```

### Benchmark using Numpy arrays as data input

[image]

### Benchmark using Python lists as input

[image]

## 2)

I replaced the `zip()` function by explicit loops, however, it didn't make much of a difference. The code would be:

#### CPython

```
def py_lstsqr(x, y):
    """ Computes the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation. """
    len_x = len(x)
    x_avg = sum(x)/len_x
    y_avg = sum(y)/len(y)
    var_x = 0
    cov_xy = 0
    for i in range(len_x):
        temp = (x[i] - x_avg)
        var_x += temp**2
        cov_xy += temp*(y[i] - y_avg)
    slope = cov_xy / var_x
    y_interc = y_avg - slope*x_avg
    return (slope, y_interc)
```

#### Cython

```
%load_ext cythonmagic

%%cython
def cy_lstsqr(x, y):
    """ Computes the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation. """
    cdef double x_avg, y_avg, var_x, cov_xy,\
         slope, y_interc, x_i, y_i
    cdef int len_x
    len_x = len(x)
    x_avg = sum(x)/len_x
    y_avg = sum(y)/len(y)
    var_x = 0
    cov_xy = 0
    for i in range(len_x):
        temp = (x[i] - x_avg)
        var_x += temp**2
        cov_xy += temp*(y[i] - y_avg)
    slope = cov_xy / var_x
    y_interc = y_avg - slope*x_avg
    return (slope, y_interc)
```

#### Numba

```
from numba import jit

@jit
def numba_lstsqr(x, y):
    """ Computes the least-squares solution to a linear matrix equation. """
    len_x = len(x)
    x_avg = sum(x)/len_x
    y_avg = sum(y)/len(y)
    var_x = 0
    cov_xy = 0
    for i in range(len_x):
        temp = (x[i] - x_avg)
        var_x += temp**2
        cov_xy += temp*(y[i] - y_avg)
    slope = cov_xy / var_x
    y_interc = y_avg - slope*x_avg
    return (slope, y_interc)
```

Comment: For your first example, I wouldn't expect numba to produce major gains, since you are doing all the computation in numpy anyway.

Comment: Thanks, any suggestions how I can implement it in Numba to compare it to CPython? From the Numba documentation I read "Numba is an just-in-time specializing compiler which compiles annotated Python and NumPy code to LLVM (through decorators). ", so I thought it would benefit from Numpy code too

Comment: From the examples on the Numba page, I would expect it might speed up code that uses Python-code loops over numpy structures, but your example does nothing except call numpy functions, which are already written in C.  I don't know much about Numba, but my guess would be you aren't going to be able to speed up your first example.  The lack of speedup on the second example is a bit more surprising, we will see if someone who knows more about Numba replies.

Comment: This is why I also implemented it as "classic" approach, where I don't use Numpy at all. I added a figure to show you that Cython is improving the performance significantly by compiling it to C, but Numba doesn't.

Comment: The fastest method may be to use `np.linalg.lstsq` rather than implementing the normal equations.

Comment: Fantastic repository, by the way.

Comment: Thanks, but np.linalg.lstsq is in fact slower! The fastest approach is implementing the "classic" one in Cython. I have done the benchmark Cython vs. numpy (np.linalg.lstsq) vs. scipy (scipy.stats.linregress) [here](http://sebastianraschka.com/IPython_htmls/cython_least_squares.html#showdown)

Comment: @BrenBarn No, that's only half of the truth ;) I am using Numpy (on purpose) only for one comparison: numba_mat_lstsqr(x, y) vs. py_mat_lstsqr(x, y). And the second comparison numba_lstsqr(x, y) vs  py_lstsqr(x, y) is completely without numpy

Comment: @SebastianRaschka: Yes, maybe I was unclear.  By "your first example" I meant the comparison between `py_mat_lstsqr` and `numba_mat_lstsqr` (which doesn't surprise me).  But what I call "your second example" is the comparison between `numba_lstsqr` and `py_lstsqr` (which does surprise me).  Googling around, I see a few cases where someone said Numba wasn't able to infer the types in some functions so there was no speedup, but I don't know enough about Numba to know if that's what's happening here, or how to improve it.

Comment: @BrenBarn Thanks for the clarification! Yes, this is surprising me too, and I am just wondering if there is something to be done about it. When I use Cython for example, I have a ~30x improvements when I don't change the code at all, and a ~80x improvement when I add static type declarations

Comment: @SebastianRaschka, Cython *is not giving you a speed boost without type declarations*. Your `%pylab inline` call is overwriting the `sum` builtin, which messes up your timings. I've told you this. [I wrote this bunch of code to *prove* it to you.](https://github.com/Veedrac/Time-Least-Squares) So why are you still saying "I have a ~30x improvements when I don't change the code at all"?...

Comment: Is this about CPython or Cython? Maybe changing the title of the question should be considered.

Comment: @Veedrac Yes, but this shouldn't be a problem, since the timing is done BEFORE I load %pylab

Comment: @JonasWielicki actually it is Numba vs. CPython, and just for comparison I added Cython vs. CPython

Comment: @Veedrac I will go ahead and replace those %pylab inlines by %matplotlib inlines, which I believe aren't doing this. Also I will make sure to restart the kernel after each timing/plotting step. This will take a while, also I will remove the zip() to see how Numba will do then... thanks again

Comment: @SebastianRaschka I don't see how you can say that when it is literally the third block in your iPython notebook. :/

Comment: I updated the original post - the problem was caused by numpy arrays that I passed as input ... but I am still not happy with the performance, or is this the most I can get for this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what I think is happening with Numba:

Numba works on `Numpy` arrays. Nothing else. Everything else has nothing to do with `Numba`.

`zip` returns an iterator of arbitrary items, which Numba cannot see into. Thus Numba cannot do much compiling.

Looping over the indexes with a `for i in range(...)` is likely to produce a much better result and allow much stronger type inference.

Comment: Thanks! I will rewrite it and redo the benchmark this weekend. I will let you know about the results!

Comment: the zip didn't do that much ... I replaced it now, but the real problem was the numpy array that I passed as input.

Comment: As I understand, it's not so much that Numba can't see into anything outside of Numpy, but that the way it handles such things is no improvement. Check out [Numba - Tell Those C++ Bullies to Get Lost](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1AwG0T4gaO0) for a great explanation of a lot of Numba.

Answer (score 2):

Using the builtin sum() could be causing problems.

Here's linear regression code that will run faster in Numba:

```
@numba.jit
def ols(x, y):
    """Simple OLS for two data sets."""
    M = x.size

    x_sum = 0.
    y_sum = 0.
    x_sq_sum = 0.
    x_y_sum = 0.

    for i in range(M):
        x_sum += x[i]
        y_sum += y[i]
        x_sq_sum += x[i] ** 2
        x_y_sum += x[i] * y[i]

    slope = (M * x_y_sum - x_sum * y_sum) / (M * x_sq_sum - x_sum**2)
    intercept = (y_sum - slope * x_sum) / M

    return slope, intercept
```